# CSS pseudo classes :hover and :active not working

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

So I wanted to try and make a game but I ran into a CSS problem right away. As you can tell by the question, the pseudo-classes that I am trying to use are not working. If you want to look at my code it's right here.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkp08kdv/1/)

**CSS**

```
#button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: blue;
};

#button:hover {
    border: 3px solid black;
};

#button:active {
    border: 2px solid black;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="button">
        <p>
            Click here to get some money!
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Basically all I'm trying to do is expand and contract the border when the user clicks on the div so that it looks more like they are pressing an actual button.

Comment: there are syntax error in your css. remove`;` after bracket

Comment: http://csslint.net/

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll make sure to use that from now on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove unnecessary semicolons `;`

```css
#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: blue;
}

#button:hover {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#button:active {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <p>
    Click here to get some money!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I'm kind of embarrassed now

Comment: Yeah I tried to for some reason it's delaying me but i will make sure to do it when it lets me